# Class Asyntask error

Tags: android

I'm developing an android application , my problem is that  I can't execute my asyntask class after clicking on a button but it works normally when I called it in my program 
I have in logcat the error : "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.”
here is my class :

```
ts.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {   
    public void onClick(View v) {
        jr=2;
        emp trs=new emp();
        trs.execute();
    }
});
       emp t=new emp();
t.execute();
private class emp extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try{
        url = new URL("....");
        HttpURLConnection httpconn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        httpconn.connect();
        if (httpconn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
             BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpconn.getInputStream()),8192);
             while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                 ja = new JSONArray(line);}
                for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jo = null;j=0;
                jo = (JSONObject) ja.getJSONObject(i);
                 ch = jo.getString("bgcolor");
                ch1=jo.getString("duree_heure");
                ch2=jo.getString("debut_heure");
                ch4=jo.getString("matiere");
                j=Integer.parseInt(ch2);
                ch2=trans(j,ch1);
                ch5=jo.getString("idsalle");
                ch6=salle(ch5);
                addvi(v,ch,ch6,ch2,ch4);                     
                }
             input.close(); 
     }
    }catch (JSONException e){
    System.out.print("vérifier !");e.printStackTrace();} catch (MalformedURLException e) {e.printStackTrace();} catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    return null;
    }
}
```

so can anyone helps me please ?

Comment: What does this do `addvi(v,ch,ch6,ch2,ch4);`??

Comment: runOnUIThread can help you

Comment: I guess the `addvi` needs wrapping in `runOnUiThread`

Comment: If `addvi(v,ch,ch6,ch2,ch4);` is in some way modifying your UI, it should be called in onPostExecute. You can't modify your UI in `doInBackground`

Comment: People, `runOnUiThread()` should not be needed or used, IMHO, with `AsyncTask`. The class has methods specifically for handling `UI` updates.

Comment: here is the function addvi ;
public void addvi(View v,String ch,String ch1,String ch2,String ch4){
 LinearLayout l= (LinearLayout) findViewById (R.id.liste);
 v=View.inflate(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.dyn_emploi, null);
 t3=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.heure);
    t5=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.salle);
    t5.setText(ch1);
     t5.setTextColor(R.color.noir);
     t3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(ch));
     t3.setText(ch4);
     t3.setTextColor(R.color.noir);
     t5.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(ch));
     l.addView(v);
}

Comment: @codeMagic is right. You have `onPostExecute` and `onPreExeccute`  and `onProgresUpdate()` invoked on the ui thread and `runOnUiThread` is not needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's caused by the fact that when you are inside [`doInBackground`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground%28Params...%29) you are inside another thread too and since it's forbidden to edit/remove/etc views create from another thread (in this case UI thread) it throw this error.

Since you didn't posted the full code, the only thing which could case this problem is `addvi(v,ch,ch6,ch2,ch4);` so you should use [`runOnUiThread`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) method of Activity to execute the method from the main thread.

But you **should** rethink your logic to work better with Asynctask methods [`onPreExecute`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPreExecute%28%29) / [`onPostExecute`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29) which is used to work with UI and are called and execute in the main thread (UI thread).

P.S To work better with the methods i said above, you should know what means the three generic in the `extends`[`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)`<Params, Progress, Result>`

The three types used by an asynchronous task are the following:

> **Params**, the type of the parameters sent to the task upon execution.
>
> **Progress**, the type of the progress units published during the background computation.
>
> **Result**, the type of the result of the background computation.

Edit: As other noticed in comments you have [`onProgressUpdate`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate%28Progress...%29) too which is invoked by you from [`doBackground`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground%28Params...%29) method using [`publishProgress`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#publishProgress%28Progress...%29)

Answer (score 0):

you cannot touch or modify view in the doInBackground function of asynctask all UI work need to be done on UI thread or main thread.I think you are doing some UI work so do it in onPostExecute() method